# Object-Oriented Programming Languages based on assignment

Tags: pl.programming-languages, object-oriented

Is it correct to claim that an object-oriented programming language based on assignment (e.g., Java and Smalltalk) introduces mutability and hence complexity in concurrent applications ?
In other words: is there a direct correlation between a language being based on assignment and mutability ?

Comment: Single assignment is fine. Re-assignment is the problem. I think if you wrote a utility for Java like Scala's styleCheck then your programmers would be at least warned where they are re-assigning things.